# How do I execute a job for specific branch/tag on Gitlab CI 5.4+?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

Latest `CHANGELOG` on the Gitlab CI [github.com repo](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/master/CHANGELOG) states that

> - Job can be branch specific or tag specific or both

Has anyone tried this feature? How would I go about making a build for a specific branch? I have not seen any obvious options for it.

[Here is a screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ufw7u98zdn45tjh/gitlabci.png) of the new **Job** page view.

- The **Trigger** option lets you choose between build for commits, tags or both.
- AFAIK, and based on the help message, the **Tags** input is for determining which *Runner* (or group or them) should run this job, as you can associate arbitrary tags with them. These are *not git tags*. Am I correct? Regardless, this is rather confusing.

So, where can I configure branch/tag names for any particular job?

In my scenario, what I want to achieve is the following:

- A push to `master` should run tests, perform a release and deploy to a *production-like* server.
- A Merge Request from any feature branch to `master`, should just run tests and report coverage.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by specifying the branches under the `only:` attribute in your `gilab-ci.yml`:

```
production:
  script:
    - echo 'hello world'
  only:
    - master
```

For another example, see [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/06/08/implementing-gitlab-ci-dot-yml/).

Answer (score 3):

in GitLab CI 5.2 you can add a condition like

```
if [ "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" == "master" ]; then
   //run jobs specific to master branch
fi
```

or

```
if [ "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" != "master" ]; then
   // skip if not on master branch
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Ok, that is useful. But, what about the `CHANGELOG` line I was talking about, then? How can I configure an entire job to run on a single branch? Do I have to write those conditionals in every script?

Comment: Moreover, your approach doesn't seem to be working on Gitlab CI 5.4.0. All my builds end on the very first line: `if [ "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" == "master" ]; then` and do not continue beyond that (even if the branch **is**, indeed, `master`)

Comment: **UPDATE**: I believe this (^) is due to a bug in this version of the CI. I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/542) over at their github.com repo.